# Error while deploying ear in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I am migrating EJB application from OC4j to JBoss AS7, I am able to deploy ear on JBoss, however i am getting one New missing/unsatisfied dependencies error in console, console log is mentioned below:

```
17:30:38,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS014211: No jndi bindings will be created for EJB Demo/fixedbuild/AttributeGroup since no
 views are exposed
17:30:39,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "Demo.ear" (runtime-name : "Demo.ear")
17:30:39,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.DemoManagementDataSource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Demo
.Demo-framework-ejb.Demo/framework/PerformanceMeasurementHome.env.jdbc.DemoManagementDataSource, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Demo.Demo-framework-ejb.Demo/framework/VisualizationEnvironmentHome.env.jdbc.DemoManagementDataSource, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Demo.Demo-framework-ejb.Demo/framework/UseCaseHome.env.jdbc.DemoManagementDataSource]

17:30:39,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
17:30:39,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:30:39,545 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.2.GA (AS 7.4.2.Final-redhat-2) started (with errors) in 12138ms - Started 2
080 of 2226 services (108 services failed or missing dependencies, 95 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Can anyone guide me, what is this error and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Check your server log. There should be Exception for the missing dependency. Attach error.

Comment: it was related to datasource issue, after defining datasource problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi did you create a module for your JDBC connections? https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7

if so then you need to create a module dependency in your WAR / EAR to the module create. eg in your MANIFEST.MF you should have a line:

Dependencies: com.mysql

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7 for more info.